# pause/resume jquery .animate()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using jquery to animate an object.

I am looking for a way to pause the animation on mouseover, and resume it after the mouse has left.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Pause-Resume-animation) plug-in will do the trick.

Comment: This script seems to have atleast one memory leak, and does not do an exact pause.play :(

Answer (score 0):

[This Pause plugin](http://tobia.github.com/Pause/) is smoother, and works natively with the standard jQuery animate() method