# Start animation after its been stopped

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

The code below stops an animation, I would like be able to start it again thou, on mouseleave

```
$(function animate(){
$(".block").animate({left: '+=500px'}, 2000);
$(".block").animate({left: '0px'}, 1, animate);
});

$(".block").mouseenter(function(){
$(".block").stop( true, false);
});

$(".block").mouseleave(function(){
animate();//This does not work
});
```

Comment: If you put this on jsfiddle, it would be easier for people to point you at a working answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [pause/resume jquery .animate() ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970835/pause-resume-jquery-animate)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to access a named function in a scope in which it's not defined?

```
function animate(){
  $(".block").animate({left: '+=500px'}, 2000);
  $(".block").animate({left: '0px'}, 1, animate);
};

$(animate);

$(".block").mouseenter(function(){
  $(".block").stop( true, false);
});

$(".block").mouseleave(function(){
  animate();
});
```

I've created [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jabley/RwNw8/), which may help you iterate to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try Hover to activate the animation.

```
$(".block").hover(stop(),start());
function stop(){
  $(".block").stop( true, false);
});
function start(){
  $(".block").animate({left: '+=500px'}, 2000);
  $(".block").animate({left: '0px'}, 1, animate);
});
```