# JQuery, Starting a function again. . . . ? animation-queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, animation, queue

Ok so here's the main function:

```
function updown(){
  var bottom = $(document).height()-$(window).height();
  //scroll to bottom. scroll to 0. and execute updown().
  $('body')
    .animate({scrollTop:bottom},20000)
    .animate({scrollTop:0},2000,updown);
}
updown();
```

Then I'm using:

```
$('body').stop(true);
```

On a button click to stop the animation-queue

My Question is how would I start the animation queue again? 
So for example `$('body').play(true);` if you get what I'm saying (though i know its not as simple as that lol). . .

Thank you in advance for any help at all!

Comment: I guess you need something like pause and resume. if so, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586068/jquery-pause-resume-animate and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970835/pause-resume-jquery-animate

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just calling updown() again?

Comment: He needs some kind of pause and resume as I understand

Comment: @MCSenstrum, please explain more details. If this is a comment, please add as comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="go">Go</button>
<button id="stop">STOP!</button>

function updown(){
 ...
}

updown();

/* Stop animation */
$("#stop").click(function(){
    $(".body").stop();
});

/* Start animation */
$("#go").click(function(){
    updown();
});
```

More about this: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: For whatever reason calling the updown(); function again isn't working I have no idea why I already tried it and it didn't work, perhaps it might be the program I'm using ~ Edge animate.