# Pause/resume a series of fadeIn/fadeOuts

Tags: jquery

Say I have a series of divs (#scene1, #scene2, #scene3, etc.) that are fading in/out, one after the other within a function, is there any way how I can click on button to pause these fadein/outs and then resume them again?

```
fooBar() {
  $("#scene1").fadeIn(500, function() {     
    $("#scene1").delay(5000).fadeOut(500, function() {          
      $("#scene2").delay(1000).fadeIn(500, function() {             
        $("#scene2").delay(5000).fadeOut(500, function() {    
          $("#scene3").delay(5000).fadeIn(500, function() {    
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

So, basically, click on a button to pause in between #scene2/#scene3, then another button to resume? There could be more than three scenes and the pause/resume could happen at any point.  Thanks.

Comment: A quick search of SO shows numerous similar questions, but they all recommend a third-party plugin.  eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970835/pause-resume-jquery-animate?rq=1

Comment: @freedomn-m I thought that was only if I was using .animate - would they still work with .fadeIn/.fadeOut?

Comment: @Martin fadeIn/fadeOut are an animate call in disguise. Try opening your console and typing `jQuery().fadeOut`, you'll get: `(a,c,d){return this.animate(b,a,c,d)}`

Comment: @NicoSantangelo Thank you. I've just confirmed that in the console; I didn't realise that this was the case.

Answer (score 2):

As per @nicoSantangelo and @freedomn-m comments above, my answer was to use a pause plugin: [pause/resume jquery .animate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970835/pause-resume-jquery-animate?rq=1)

I did not know .fadeIn/.fadeOut methods were using an animate call in disguise.